# Find next date after date value in column (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to build a query with 2 tables, `Orders` and `Repairs`. The goal is to find the first repair date after the order date for any particular customer, with 'null' if there were no repairs between orders. Here are the current columns for each:

```
CustomerID LocationID SaleDate
-------------------------------
1          1b         1/10/2019
1          1b         2/23/2019
1          1c         1/29/2019
2          2a         3/01/2019
2          2a         3/25/2019

CustomerID LocationID RepairDate
--------------------------------
1          1b         2/25/2019
1          1c         2/13/2019
1          1c         2/27/2019
2          2a         3/03/2019
2          2a         3/17/2019
```

Here is the expected result. Any ideas? For some reason nothing I've tried seems to work

```
CustomerID LocationID SaleDate  RepairDate
-------------------------------------------
1          1b         1/10/2019 null
1          1b         2/23/2019 2/25/2019
1          1c         1/29/2019 2/13/2019
2          2a         3/1/2019  3/3/2019
2          2a         3/25/2019 null
```

Comment: Just as a note: I'm sure *you are aware* that SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 are **out of extended support** by now - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-end-of-sql-server-2008-and-2008-r2-extended-support/ - time to upgrade!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit long-winded but was the best way that occurred to me to prevent the same repair from being matched to all previous sales which I believe is the one issue with Gordon Linoff's far simpler answer. I have unioned your two tables into a single event log then used the row_number window function to identify sequences of events affecting the same customer and location. Try it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/56747/14)

```
WITH eventlog
     AS (SELECT *,
                Row_number()
                  OVER(
                    partition BY customerid, locationid
                    ORDER BY eventdate) AS seq
         FROM   (SELECT customerid,
                        locationid,
                        saledate AS eventdate,
                        's'      AS type
                 FROM   orders
                 UNION
                 SELECT customerid,
                        locationid,
                        repairdate AS repairdate,
                        'r'        AS type
                 FROM   repairs) a)
SELECT s.customerid,
       s.locationid,
       s.eventdate AS saledate,
       r.eventdate AS repairdate
FROM   eventlog s
       LEFT JOIN eventlog r
              ON s.seq + 1 = r.seq
                 AND s.customerid = r.customerid
                 AND s.locationid = r.locationid
                 AND r.type = 'r'
WHERE  s.type = 's';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `outer apply`:

```
select o.*, r.*
from orders o outer apply
     (select top (1) r.*
      from repairs r
      where r.customerId = o.customerId and
            r.locationid = o.locationid and
            r.RepairDate > o.SaleDate
      order by r.RepairDate
     ) r;
```

Note:  You specify that you want the first repair date for the *customer*.  However, the data suggests that you really mean customer/location combination.

EDIT:

Thank you for setting up the SQL Fiddle.  That clarifies the issue.  I think this tweak does what you want:

-- Answer from Gordon Linoff

```
select o.*, r.*
from (select o.*,
             lead(saledate) over (partition by customerid order by saledate) as next_salesdate
      from orders o
     ) o outer apply
     (select top (1) r.*
      from repairs r
      where r.customerId = o.customerId and
            r.locationid = o.locationid and
            r.RepairDate > o.SaleDate and
            (r.RepairDate < o.next_salesdate or o.next_salesdate is null)
      order by r.RepairDate
     ) r;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/56747/20) is the db<>fiddle.

Comment: I assume from the expected output the OP _does_ want the `locationId` in the correlation clause. However, would this answer produce the `null` values as required? The logic seems to be that a sale followed by another sale has `null` repair date.

Comment: @SimonN . . . Yes, it will return the `NULL` values if there is no match.

Comment: I think you end up with one less null than the expected output. I've put both our answers in a fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/56747/14